# Sql server : How to use "NOT IN" Query in stored procedure instead of left join?

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, notin

My current code snippet is  given below. I want to use "NOT IN" query instead of left join.

```
    from Complaints C
    inner join Employees E on E.ID = C.EmployeeID 
    left join ComplaintInfractionMapping CIM on CIM.ComplaintID = C.ID
```

How to use "NOT IN" Query in stored procedure . In below code there is syntax error.

```
    from Complaints C
    inner join Employees E on E.ID = C.EmployeeID 
    NOT IN SELECT InfractionComment,InfractionDate FROM ComplaintInfractionMapping where ComplaintID =  C.ID
```

Comment: are you sure, are you want to use Not In? because Joins are faster than In / Not In clause

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this way :-

```
from    Complaints C
        inner join Employees E on E.ID = C.EmployeeID 
Where   Not Exists (    SELECT   InfractionComment
                                ,InfractionDate 
                        FROM    ComplaintInfractionMapping 
                        where   ComplaintID =  C.ID
                    )
```